# Should I share the Materializer instance or always create a new one when needed?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm currently working on a project that extensively uses Akka and Akka Streams.

One question/problem keeps coming up while working with it: What is the best practice for the Materializer which is needed in all places where streams are used. Especially when I'm inside an Actor, where I only can access the ActorSystem, should I manually pass in an existing Materializer instance or just create one when I need it?

I'm especially worried about the resource usage and performance when instantiating Materializers on demand.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The creation of `ActorMaterializer`s is fairly cheap and having a reasonable proliferation of them shouldn't be an issue in the majority of cases.

If you chase the chain of calls starting from `ActorMaterializer.apply` (see [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/ActorMaterializer.scala#L38)) you'll find that `ActorMaterializer` (or better, `ActorMaterializerImpl`) is not performing anything significant at creation time.

Just to give you an idea of how it compares to an `ActorSystem` creation, consider the following code

```
  val sysStart = System.nanoTime()
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("mySystem")
  val sysDuration = FiniteDuration(System.nanoTime() - sysStart, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  println(s"System creation: ${sysDuration.toMillis} ms")

  val matStart = System.nanoTime()
  val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(actorSystem)
  val matDuration = FiniteDuration(System.nanoTime() - matStart, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  println(s"Materializer creation: ${matDuration.toMillis} ms")
```

outputs this on my laptop

> System creation: 901 ms
>
> Materializer creation: 14 ms

However, as Johan pointed out in the comments, it is important to add that materializers' lifecycle needs to be properly managed, invoking `shutdown` whenever they stop being useful, to avoid leaking resources.

To recap, passing a materializer around whenever possible is a sound choice. Whenever this is not convenient though, its creation is cheap, but pay attention to shut it down properly.

Comment: I think lifecycle and lifecycle management is more important than performance. If you `shutdown` a materializer all its running streams are abruptly terminated, if you create a materializer in an actor and do not shut it down when you are stopping the actor you are leaking resources.

Comment: Definitely agree with that, and anyway performance is not massively skewed with either of the 2 choices. `mat.shutdown()` should always be included in the `postStop` method of your actor.